# multiple post array loop doesn't working

Tags: php, sql, arrays, mysqli

```
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM product ORDER BY product_id DESC";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

            echo "" . $row["product"] . "\n\n<input type='checkbox' name='product[]' value=" .$row["product"] . ">\n         
     Quantity\n\n<select name='quantity[]'>
        <option value='1'>1</option>
        <option value='2'>2</option>
        <option value='3'>3</option>
    </select><br />";
        }

    ?>
    <button name="submit" type="submit">submit</button><br />

    <?php

        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            if (is_array($_POST['product'])) {
                foreach ($_POST['product'] as $key => $product_name) {
                    $quantity = $_POST['quantity'][$key];
                    echo $product_name . "\n";
                    echo $quantity . "<br>";

                }
            }
        }
    }

    ?>
```

i would want to select multiple product and quantity but it doesn't giving me quantity value what i select.

[image: example picture1]
on example picture1 you could see i selected 2 products

- Asus 2
- Acer 3

But if click on submit i get result like
[image: example picture2]

- Asus 1
- Acer 1

Comment: The first and second dropdown have value 1 so the results are correct. All quantity values are always submitted.

Comment: Your issue is that only checked checkboxes are posted, but all selects are posted. So you need to need to link the 2 together so that they keys match. You can add a simple counter var, ie. `$i=0`, `name='product[$i]'`/`name='quantity[$i]'`

Comment: did you see what product i selected? @Maarten van Middelaar

Comment: i appreciate your help but im just a learner, not expert on php. Would you please correct my script and post it here? @Sean

Comment: @MaartenvanMiddelaar posted an answer that is equivalent to what I mentioned. My example was to use a simple counter var, where he used `$row['product_id']` (or whatever your row id column name is).

Comment: Yes.  Credits are yours @Sean. No need for counters if we have product_id (as we can see in the sql query)

Comment: Thanks both you guys. @Maarten van Middelaar answer is perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the product ID to link the checkboxed to the select boxes.:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM product ORDER BY product_id DESC";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

            echo "" . $row["product"] . "\n\n<input type='checkbox' name='product[".$row['product_id']."]' value=" .$row["product"] . ">\n         
     Quantity\n\n<select name='quantity[".$row['product_id']."]'>
        <option value='1'>1</option>
        <option value='2'>2</option>
        <option value='3'>3</option>
    </select><br />";
        }
```

Comment: Perfect... You are amazing. Thank you.